# Zipping or Compressing files through command prompt

Tags: winrar, winzip

I want to zip or rar large number of files fast, doing it in windows talking lot of time, so I thought zipping using Windows Command Prompt can be faster.

Please suggest if it is possible doing it? if yes please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running from the command prompt will not perform much differently than doing it through windows explorer.

Some ZIP programs such as [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) can leverage multiple CPUs to speed the task of zipping.

7-Zip can be used from Windows Explorer or from the command line.  Performance will be the same, just select the UI you are more comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

Open up commandline and navigate to your WinRar directory, typically:

```
C:\Program Files\WinRAR
```

You then type:

```
rar a -r [directory and filename to where you want to save].rar [directory_to_files]
```

For example:

```
rar a -r c:\Users\Bob\Desktop\myrar.rar c:\Users\Bob\Desktop\my_files
```

Doing it in commandline will not speed the process up. However, it will be unnoticeable.